# Eslint rule for unnecessary nullish coalesce and optional chaining in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint

Consider these cases:

```
const obj = {};
obj ?? {};
obj?.prop;
```

Both the nullish coalesce and optional chaining were unnecessary, is there an Eslint rule to catch these?

I recently encountered a bug where I did `newVal === val ?? defaultVal` instead of `newVal === (val ?? defaultVal)`. This evaluates to `boolean ?? defaultVal`. I don't think any other Eslint rules can catch this, so something like [no-unnecessary-condition](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-condition.md) might be my best bet for preventing this in the future.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this: [no-unnecessary-condition](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unnecessary-condition.md).